# Pyparsing use in C# code

Tags: c#, ironpython, pyparsing

I'm trying to execute python script which use *pyparsing* in *C#* with a help of *IronPython*. But when I try to run the script I get the **ImportException** that there is `No module named pyparsing`. I tried to add a path to a dir consisting *pyparsing*, but I still didn't managed how to run it proper way.

Here's the *C#* code:

```
string ExecutePythonScript(string path, string text)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

        string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("pyparsing-1.5.7");

        ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
        {
            paths.Add(dir);
        }
        else
        {
            paths.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        }
        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

        scope.SetVariable("text", text);
        engine.ExecuteFile(path, scope);

        return scope.GetVariable("result");
    }
```

Of course in the beggining of the python script I import *pyparsing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my friend I found what was wrong.

1. Unpacked pyparsing package had to be placed in the Debug folder of C# app in a folder named Lib. (I suppose it also could be in folder with another name, but this was faster for me.)
2. Thanks to [this page](http://anand-iyer.com/blog/2010/importerror-with-ironpython-in-c/) I also realized that I need to add some lines of code into the C# app.

So now it's:

```
    string ExecutePythonScript(string path, string text)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

        ICollection<string> Paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        Paths.Add(".");
        Paths.Add("D:\\DevTools\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib");
        Paths.Add("D:\\DevTools\\IronPython 2.7\\DLLs");
        Paths.Add("D:\\DevTools\\IronPython 2.7");
        Paths.Add("D:\\DevTools\\IronPython 2.7\\lib\\site-packages");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(Paths);

        scope.SetVariable("text", text);
        engine.ExecuteFile(path, scope);
        (...)
```

And it's at least not creating that Exception.

Comment: Can I ask you why you chose this solution (C#->IronPython) as opposed to a parser written in F# with FParsec or flex/fyacc? (I am a .net veteran, learning python - particularly parsing))

Comment: Sorry for long time of response. Our group just tried to create something for AI labs in our college and everyone took their favourite technology. This was the problem when we tried to connect it all to one project. We just didn't think about it then.